# How to POST an object with its childrens ? grails 3 RESTful - security - POST save new objects

Tags: json, grails, spring-security, http-post, restful-architecture

I am trying to do a simple `POST` to save a new object
[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbRTU.png)
I want to `POST` a Question with the following attributes:

```
String name
static hasOne = [questionType: QuestionType]
```

Each `Question` has one abstract `QuestionType` extended by one of this objects:

- `Mcq` (Multiple Choice Question)
- `SourceCode`
- `Matching`
- ...

For my `Mcq`, I have the following attributes:

```
static belongsTo = [questionType: QuestionType]
static hasMany = [propositions: Proposition]

static constraints = {
}

static mapping = {
    propositions cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
}
```

So my `Mcq` owns 0 to many `Proposition`

A `Proposition` is made of:

```
String body
Boolean isCorrect
String reason
```

I am using Postman to check my API. I don't have any UI for now.

My `Question`, `Qcm` and `Proposition` objects have a controller and a service to manage them.

My `QuestionService`:

```
class QuestionService {
    def save(Question question) {
        if (question == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }
        if (question.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond question.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }
        question.save flush:true
    }

    def update(Question question) {
        if (question == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }
        if (question.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond question.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }
        question.save flush:true
    }

    def delete(Question question) {
        if (question == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }
        question.delete flush: true
    }
}
```

My `QuestionController`:

```
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class QuestionController {

    //spring bean injected for the Controller to access the Service
    def questionService

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    //views
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Question.list(params), model:[questionCount: Question.count()]
    }

    def show(Question question) {
        respond question
    }

    //actions
    def save(Question question){
        try { questionService.save question }
        catch (e){ respond status: PRECONDITION_FAILED }
        respond question, [status: CREATED, view:"show"]
    }

    def update(Question question) {
        try { questionService.update question }
        catch (e) { respond status: PRECONDITION_FAILED }
        respond question, [status: OK, view:"show"]
    }

    def delete(Question question) {
        try { questionService.delete question }
        catch (e){ respond status: PRECONDITION_FAILED }
        respond status: OK, view:"index"
    }
}
```

I can get each `Proposition`, `Mcq` and `Question` with my index and show actions.
I don't allow my users to `POST` a new `Proposition` / `Mcq`. If they want to do it, they have to `UPDATE` the full `Question` itself. So only my `Question` can be modified (and modify others), others or in read-only.

My problem is that I can NOT `POST` this:

```
{
  "name": "name1",
  "questionType": {
    "propositions": [
        {
            "body": "body proposition 1",
            "isCorrect": true,
            "reason": "reason proposition 1"
        },
        {
            "body": "body proposition 2",
            "isCorrect": false,
            "reason": "reason proposition 2"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

It always returns me a

```
[
     null
]
```

But this works:

```
{
  "name": "name1",
  "questionType": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

So, in here, I can refer to a `QuestionType` already in my database (from my bootstrap) but I don't see how to create in cascade all of my `Question`, `QuestionType`, `Qcm` and `Proposition`.

Comment: You said Mcq extended question type, however mcq has a belongsTo to questionType. You will need to show all domain classes you are interested in persisting. There are too many things wrong here to even start

Comment: Well I am new in here. So I don't really know how to manage all of it. And it's my 1st time using an ORM.
So I should only extend my class and don't use a belongsTo ? I thouth my extend had to be linked by a belongsTo to its mother